# I had some issue in JSON data and i can get only name in Andrew and Karthick

Tags: javascript

```
const data=[{
    "name": "Andrew",
    "age": "23",
    "subject": [{
        "name": "english",
        "period": "1st"
    }]
},
{
    "name": "karthick",
    "age": "29",
    "subject": [{
        "name": "French",
        "period": "3st"
    }]
}]
```

I need to console only the name value in an array and print in console
Example:["Andrew","english","karthick","French"]

Comment: you can use flatMap. if your subject array has more than 1 you will need to do a map inside the flatMap. otherwise return `[el.name,el.subject[0].name]` in flatMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const data = [ { "name": "Andrew", "age": "23", "subject": [ { "name": "english", "period": "1st" } ] }, { "name": "karthick", "age": "29", "subject": [ { "name": "French", "period": "3st" } ] } ];

const res = data.flatMap(({ name, subject = [] }) => ([
  name,
  ...subject.map(({ name }) => name)
]));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example dataset you don't have to do anything complicated here. [Loop over the data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) and then push the name and subject name into a new array.

```js
const data=[{name:"Andrew",age:"23",subject:[{name:"english",period:"1st"}]},{name:"karthick",age:"29",subject:[{name:"French",period:"3st"}]}];

const arr = [];

for (const obj of data) {
  arr.push(obj.name);
  arr.push(obj.subject[0].name);
}

console.log(arr);
```